# Wrapped exception:org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar

Tags: java, spring, struts, sqlexception

I have a DAO like this,

```
public String getCaseTypeById(String caseIdNumber) {
        String caseType = null;

        SqlQuery caseQuery = 
            new PQuery(getDataSource());
        System.out.println("caseIdNumber   --"+caseIdNumber);
        caseType = (String)caseQuery.findObject(caseIdNumber);
        System.out.println("before return");

        return caseType;
    }
```

and pQuery is ,

```
public PlanQuery(DataSource dataSource)
{
    super();
    setDataSource(dataSource);
    BQueries bQueries = new BQueries();

    setSql(bQueries.getSelectStandardCaseTypeQuery());
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("caseIdNumber",
            Types.NUMERIC));
    compile();
}
```

where getSelectStandardCaseTypeQuery is,

```
public String getSelectStandardCaseTypeQuery() {

String selectCaseTypeByCaseId = null;

        selectCaseTypeByCaseId = 
            " SELECT ct.C_CODE as c_code " + 
            "  FROM  " + getSchemaName() + ".csummary cs, " + 
                getSchemaName() + ".ctype ct " +
            "   WHERE cs.c_number = ? " + 
            "   AND UPPER(ct.C_DESC_TEXT) = UPPER(cs.C_TYPE) ";

    return selectCaseTypeByCaseId;
}
```

Now the above return works fine. the control goes back to DAO and in DAO the sysout gets printed but after that i get the exception as,

[ SELECT ct.C_CODE as c_type_code   FROM  gpt.csummary cs, gpt.ctype ct    WHERE cs.c_number = ?    AND UPPER(ct.C_DESC_TEXT) = UPPER(cs.C_TYPE) ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:545)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:486)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
```

Wrapped exception:
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [ SELECT ct.C_CODE as c_type_code   FROM  gpt.csummary cs, gpt.ctype ct    WHERE cs.c_number = ?    AND UPPER(ct.C_DESC_TEXT) = UPPER(cs.C_TYPE) ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

Butthen when i execute the same in toad everything works fine. I see thatDB conenction schema everything is correctly pointed. But why does it fail in finObject in DAO. any inputs?

Comment: Spring and Struts together (both are controller frameworks) as indicated such by tags?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use:

```
select * from schema.table_name
```

Comment: That is how my sql looks like "schema.table_name"

Comment: is your jdbc user the same that you use to test from TOAD?